# Removing rel="nofollow" from links posted in Post Content

Tags: posts, permalinks, links, seo, nofollow

I am running wordpress for my blog [EasyPadhai](http://easypadhai.com/kc/).

I am writing a posts and I have included links to my Android app [EasyPadhai](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epblogs.easypadhai) for my users. But all links to app are turning in nofollow links. Also Social-links are becoming nofollow links.

How can I change this, so that links in post_Content become doFollow. I am not a pro-wordpress dev. Also I am using following plugins on my installation.

- Akismet
- Google Analytics for WordPress
- WordPress SEO
- W3 Total Cache

**How can I change nofollow links to do follow links for my Post Content?**

Comment: Your website do not have `nofollow` links. If you are asking about `rel="nofollow"` on your links on social media websites like facebook, twitter then you cannot do anything about it. It's their website, they add it to all links.

Comment: @Roberthue I used http://www.feedthebot.com/ and All the links I care about are Nofollow links.
Apart from feedthebot, even other tools had same result.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure why do you want external website's link to have `dofollow` tag. The theme is working fine by adding `nofollow` tag to external links. Because you don't want search engine spiders to leave your website for social/popular websites. Is there a good reason why do you want that?

Comment: @Roberthue I want spiders to leave Only to reach my own app, which is more important for me.

Comment: I posted it below. Try it and let me know. It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links are generated by `alx_social_links()` function.
So in your theme's `functions.php` file, search for `alx_social_links()` function and this link specifically.

```
echo '<li><a rel="nofollow" class="social-tooltip" '.$title.' '.$link.' '.$target.'><i '.$icon.' '.$color.'></i></a></li>';
```

and remove `rel="nofollow"` from it. So this will be the new link.

```
echo '<li><a class="social-tooltip" '.$title.' '.$link.' '.$target.'><i '.$icon.' '.$color.'></i></a></li>';
```

It will remove `nofollow` tag from these links.